Splash Not Expanding List After Button Click
On the page at https://www.diy.com/home-furniture-storage/cooking-dining/cookware.cat, there is a "Categories" list:
<section class="mb-xl">
    <h2 class="mb-md !border-x-0 !border-t-0 pb-md text-lg font-bold [border:--border-normal]" data-testid="category-filters-list-title">Categories</h2>
    <a data-testid="link-component" class="inline-flex w-auto cursor-pointer items-start no-underline" data-discover="true" href="/home-furniture-storage/cooking-dining.cat">
        <span class="my-xs text-[--color-text-light]">See more <span class="font-bold text-[--color-text]">Cooking &amp; dining</span></span>
    </a>
    <ul id=":R19lkd5:" data-testid="categories-list">
        <!-- Category list items -->
    </ul>
    <div class="py-sm">
        <button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls=":R19lkd5:" data-testid="show-more-categories" class="inline-flex w-auto cursor-pointer items-start underline hover:no-underline focus-visible:no-underline">Show more</button>
    </div>
</section>

Description:
The page initially displays a portion of the "Categories" list. When scrolling down, a "Show more" button becomes visible. Clicking this button expands the list with additional items, and the button text changes to "Show less." The DOM updates to reflect this change.
DOM Update Example:
<section class="mb-xl">
    <h2 class="mb-md !border-x-0 !border-t-0 pb-md text-lg font-bold [border:--border-normal]" data-testid="category-filters-list-title">Categories</h2>
    <a data-testid="link-component" class="inline-flex w-auto cursor-pointer items-start no-underline" data-discover="true" href="/home-furniture-storage/cooking-dining.cat">
        <span class="my-xs text-[--color-text-light]">See more <span class="font-bold text-[--color-text]">Cooking &amp; dining</span></span>
    </a>
    <ul id=":R19lkd5:" data-testid="categories-list">
        <!-- Expanded category list items -->
    </ul>
    <div class="py-sm">
        <button aria-expanded="true" aria-controls=":R19lkd5:" data-testid="show-more-categories" class="inline-flex w-auto cursor-pointer items-start underline hover:no-underline focus-visible:no-underline">Show less</button>
    </div>
</section>

Objective:
The main task is to retrieve the entire list of categories, not just a portion. To achieve this, the Lua script needs to:
Scroll down the page until the "Show more" button becomes visible.
Click the "Show more" button to expand the list, changing the aria-expanded attribute to "true".
Scan the expanded list and collect all items.
Question:
Is it possible to perform this task using Scrapy Splash? Specifically:
Scrolling down the page until the "Show more" button is visible.
Clicking the "Show more" button to ensure the list expands and the aria-expanded attribute changes to "true".
I have Splash Desktop installed, and there I tried various Lua script options with the help of ChatGPT, for example:
function main(splash)
    splash:set_viewport_size(1024, 768)
    assert(splash:go("https://www.diy.com/home-furniture-storage/cooking-dining/cookware.cat"))
    splash:wait(3)
    
    -- Scroll down to ensure the button is visible
    splash:runjs("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    splash:wait(2)
    
    -- Find and click the "Show more" button
    local js_code = [[
        var button = document.querySelector("button[data-testid='show-more-categories']");
        if (button) {
            var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': true
            });
            button.dispatchEvent(event);
            return 'Clicked';
        } else {
            return 'Button not found';
        }
    ]]
    local result = splash:runjs(js_code)
    
    -- Wait for all asynchronous processes to complete
    splash:wait(10)
    
    -- Return the HTML of the page
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        click_result = result
    }
end

The button is detected, clicked, but the list does not expand and the button's aria-expanded="false" state does not change.
